# Issue with magento multi website and different domains

Tags: magento2

I have 2 domains I want lunch it with the same Magento 
as a multi-website option in Magento.
I add (website,  store, view store ) and associated it with the second domain.
I change my .hatacsses in root Magento(first domain)
like that

```
#SetEnv MAGE_MODE developer
SetEnvIf Host .*nasseij.com.* MAGE_RUN_CODE=base
SetEnvIf Host .*nasseij.com.* MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host .*test.nasseij.com.* MAGE_RUN_CODE=sinwadi
SetEnvIf Host .*test.nasseij.com.* MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```

and

```
#RewriteBase /magento/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)nasseij\.com
RewriteRule .* – [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:base]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)nasseij\.com
RewriteRule .* – [E=MAGE_RUN_TYPE:website]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)sinwadi\.com
RewriteRule .* – [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:newsite]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)sinwadi\.com
RewriteRule .* – [E=MAGE_RUN_TYPE:website]
```

and change this in the main index of my basic Magento

```
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$params = $_SERVER;
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'base';
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication(\Magento\Framework\App\Http::class);
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

and put **.hatccses** in second domain root but didn't work it gives me that file not found.
I try copy Magento files to second domain root also give me that 500 error a lot of redirects

Do I want to know my mistakes and in the second domain which files have to be?

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this in your .htaccess, you do not need to also edit your index.php file. Additionally, the conditions you have specified with `SetEnvIf` overlap each other.

Remove all of your rules from the .htaccess file and save them in a text pad in case you need them later. Remove your changes to index.php. Right after the line `RewriteEngine on`, try this:

```
SetEnvIf Host ^nasseij MAGE_RUN_CODE=base
SetEnvIf Host ^nasseij MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host ^test\.nasseij MAGE_RUN_CODE=sinwadi
SetEnvIf Host ^test\.nasseij MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```

**OR** if your main domain begins with www, try this:

```
SetEnvIf Host ^www\.nasseij MAGE_RUN_CODE=base
SetEnvIf Host ^www\.nasseij MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host ^test\.nasseij MAGE_RUN_CODE=sinwadi
SetEnvIf Host ^test\.nasseij MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```

Depending on whether apache is looking at `index.php` or `pub/index.php`, you will need to do this in either the .htaccess file in the root of your Magento installation or the .htaccess that lives inside of the pub directory.